# Does the order in tensor definition count?

Tags: matrices, tensors

I see different books use different order in tensor definition.
[image]
[image]
I can't understand how this happens because after all in the definition of a rank 2 tensor we have matrices multiplications, that in general are not commutative. One can think that this is just a convention, that it is sufficient to keep the same convention everywhere, but probably this is not the case because I see that jacobian matrix are moved freely, for example here:
[image]
I'm confused. The terms exchanged have common indexes, and in general $a_{ir}b_{rj} \neq b_{ir} a_{rj}$ (or, other words, the $(i,j)$ term of the matrix $AB$ is different from the $(i,j)$ term of the matrix $BA$). Why the two definitions are equivalent and these movements are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factors here are just ordinary numbers, not matrices. You can think of them as the entries of matrices, though.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe the misunderstanding stems from the fact that I don't have to see it as an equation between matrices.  But rather as a set of n^2 ordinary equations?

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro. That's correct. And remember that there's an implicit summation over repeated indices (one superscript and one subscript; e.g. $t$ and $u$ in the first photo).

Comment: Thanks now I see. There are no problems related to commutativity.  We just have to pay attention to the order of the free indexes, linked to dyads, but since the others indicate sums we can move freely.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro. Normally there are no problems related to commutativity as they are just numbers (like the coefficients of a vector expanded in a basis), but in some cases they might be operators (e.g. $\nabla_i$) and then we have to be more careful.